# XML table to LaTeX

Tags: xml, xslt, latex

Suppose I have an XML table of the form

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Telephone:</td>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

that I wish to convert to LaTeX using XSLT (I stole this example elsewhere). The result I want is

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
 First name & Bill Gates &\\
 \multirow{2}{*}{Telephone:}
   & 555 77 854 &\\
   & 555 77 855 &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For the most part, there is a fair one-to-one-correspondence between the two table formats. Thus this works quite well for the most part:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

<xsl:apply-templates/>

\end{document}

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
<xsl:apply-templates/>
\end{tabular}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
<xsl:apply-templates />\\
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td[not(@rowspan) and not(@colspan)]">
<xsl:apply-templates/> &amp;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td[not(@colspoan)]">
\multirow{<xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>}{*}{<xsl:apply-templates/>} &amp;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td[not(@rowspan)]">
\multicolumn{<xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>}{l}{<xsl:apply-templates/>} &amp;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
\multirow{<xsl:value-of select="@rowspan"/>}{*}{\multicolumn{<xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>}}{l}{<xsl:apply-templates/>} &amp;
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is the `&amp;`s (which become `&` in the output). In LaTeX, you need one in the beginning of the third row, where the spanned cell is. This is not the case in the XML table. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Is the XSLT in your question entirely representative of the issue you are facing? It's just that one of the template outputs the text `\multicolumn` which is not actually shown in your expected output. Also, the XSLT refers to a `no` function, which I think should actually be `not`. There are also a couple of syntax errors too. There is a missing `"` in the template that matches `table` and a missing `]` in the template that matches `td[no(@rowspan)`. If you could correct all these, that would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: No, there will be times when `\multicolumn' will be used as well. But it's mostly `\multirow` that's causing trouble. I had to make a simplified version for this question specifically. I shall try to correct the errors you mention.

Comment: why are you putting `\cr` into the latex? (it's not a latex command) I think you intended `&` didn't you, since you are adding them every td

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, originally, I did so because `&` cases trouble in XML because it has to be written `&amp;`. I then decided to use `\cr` instead, to avoid confusion. I planned to silently replace it by `&amp;` in the final output anyway. But after reading your comment, I redecided and therefore changed it.

Comment: `\cr` was a particularly disturbing choice as it's a tex primitive that would completely mess up the table if used after every cell:-)

Comment: You're changing the question as you go. Your original question was how to escape &, right now you want to do intricate rowspan/colspan things. This is frustrating for the people answering, even if you start a bonus. The better way to go about this is to start a new question for a new issue.

Comment: I haven't changed the question one bit. What you say are two different formulations of the same thing. The problem is that LaTeX  and my XML document handle colspans and rowspans differently. The question is how to write a code that translates between these two systems. That has been the point all along.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
<xsl:apply-templates/>
\end{document}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
<xsl:variable name="noc" select="max(tr/sum(td/(@colspan/number(.),1)[1]))"/>
<xsl:text>\begin{tabular}{*{</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$noc"/>
<xsl:text>}{l}}&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]">
 <xsl:with-param name="rspans" select="for $i in 1 to xs:integer($noc) return 0"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:text>\end{tabular}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
 <xsl:param name="rspans"/>
<xsl:text/>% [<xsl:value-of select="$rspans"/>]
 <xsl:variable name="tr" select="."/>
 <xsl:for-each select="$rspans">
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="td" select="$tr/td[count($rspans[position() &lt;=$c][.=0])]"/>
  <xsl:if test=".=0">
   <xsl:if test="$td/@rowspan[. &gt; 1]">
    <xsl:text>\multirow{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$td/@rowspan"/>
    <xsl:text>}{*}{</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$td"/>
   <xsl:if test="$td/@rowspan[. &gt; 1]">}</xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=". &gt;1 and position()=last()">&amp;\\&#10;</xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="position()=last()">\\&#10;</xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>&amp;</xsl:otherwise>  
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tr[1]">
  <xsl:with-param name="rspans" select="for $c in 1 to count($rspans)
   return
   ($rspans[$c] +
   td[count($rspans[position() &lt;=$c][.=0])]/(@rowspan,1)[1]
   -1)"/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you remove `multirow`, please? ;-)

Comment: @egreg This is so not tex.sx the customer is always right:-)

Comment: Thank you for a lot for the brilliant answer, @DavidCarlisle. I'm currently playing around with it, but there appears to be no support for several `\multirow` columns next to each other. Furthermore, there is no `\multicolumn` support. Would it be difficult to get these two things to work?

Comment: @Gaussler multirow was supposed to be fully supported so if that isn't I may look later. multicolumn isn't supported here, I was planning to leave it as an exercise for the reader (it's not hard you just need to propagate colspan entries in the rowspan parameter rather than just 1) I may leave some multicol hints or do it while fixing multispan, may need to be the weekend...

Comment: Well, I do see how I can get `\multicolumn` to work in this case; I mostly said it to ask whether there was some specific reason why you hadn't included it. This appears not to have been the case.

Comment: @Gaussler I have yet to see a table using `\multirow` that can't be improved by removing it.

Comment: It's kinda not my fault that the XML document I'm converting is using it. :-P

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is the fix causing trouble? :-)

Comment: @Gaussler no strange enough I forgot you:-) will look later.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I hate to ask the same question again, but... :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, perhaps a bounty will motivate you? ;-)

Comment: Never heard of this "real life" thing. ;-)

Comment: Well, I might as well give you the bounty. Better than losing the points entirely.