# XML table to latex table - How to handle @rowspan correct

Tags: html, xslt, html-table, xslt-2.0

I am having a table like this:

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" rowspan="5" colspan="1">New</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="5" colspan="1">some text</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Computer</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Microsoft, Apple Inc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">A</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">B</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">C</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">D</td>
    <td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1">d</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

which I need to convert like this:

```
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \multirow{5}{\linewidth}{New} & 
    \multirow{5}{\linewidth}{some text} & 
    {Computer} & 
    {Microsoft, Apple Inc}
    \\
    &&{A} & 
    {a}
    \\
    &&{B} & 
    {b}
    \\
    &&{C} & 
    {c}
    \\
    &&{D} & 
    {d}
    \\
    \end{tabular}
```

with this XSL code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      version="2.0"
      >

    <xsl:output 
      method="text" 
      indent="no" />

    <xsl:template name="getMaxCols">
      <xsl:for-each select="../../../tbody/tr">
        <xsl:sort select="count(th|td)" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
          <xsl:variable name="maxCtr">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test=".//*[@colspan]">
                <xsl:sequence select="sum(.//@colspan)"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="count(td)"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="$maxCtr" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getRowSpan">
     <xsl:param name="totalcols" />
     <xsl:param name="thisrow" />
     <xsl:param name="thiscol" />
     <xsl:param name="thisrowcols" />
     <xsl:param name="thiscolspanpos" />
     <xsl:param name="node" />
     <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not($totalcols = $thisrowcols)">
       <!-- Loop through each rows from 1 to $thisrow -->
       <xsl:for-each select="../../tr[position() > 0 and position() &lt; $thisrow]">
        <xsl:variable name="tmpRow" select="position()" />
        <xsl:variable name="colspanCtr">0</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*[position() &lt; number($thiscol + 1)]">
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="
                           number(count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = $thiscol and 
                           @rowspan &gt; 1 and 
                           number(@rowspan + $tmpRow) &gt; $thisrow
                         ">
            <xsl:for-each select="
                                  ../*[@rowspan &gt; 1][following-sibling::*[@rowspan=1]] 
                                  ">
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 0">&amp;</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
     </xsl:choose><xsl:text/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:text/>\begin{tabular}{<xsl:for-each select="tbody/tr[1]/td"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@align, 1, 1)" /></xsl:for-each>}<xsl:text/>
    <xsl:text/><xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/><xsl:text/>
    <xsl:text/>\end{tabular}<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbody"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr"><xsl:apply-templates />\\</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
       <xsl:variable name="colspanpos">0</xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="rowpos"><xsl:value-of select="number(count(../preceding-sibling::tr) + 1)" /></xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="rowcols"><xsl:value-of select="number(count(../td))" /></xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="colpos"><xsl:value-of select="number(position() div 2)" /></xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="tabcols"><xsl:call-template name="getMaxCols"/></xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="colspanpos" select="sum(for $i in ../*[position() &lt; $colpos + 1] return number($colspanpos + number($i/@colspan)))" />
       <xsl:call-template name="getRowSpan">
         <xsl:with-param name="totalcols" select="$tabcols"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="thisrow" select="$rowpos" />
         <xsl:with-param name="thisrowcols" select="$rowcols" />
         <xsl:with-param name="thiscol" select="$colpos" />
         <xsl:with-param name="thiscolspanpos" select="$colspanpos" />
         <xsl:with-param name="node" select="local-name()" />
       </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@colspan &gt; 1">\multicolumn{<xsl:value-of select="@colspan" />}{<xsl:value-of select="substring(@align, 1, 1)" />}{<xsl:if test="@rowspan &gt; 1">\multirow{<xsl:value-of select="@rowspan" />}{\linewidth}{</xsl:if><xsl:apply-templates /><xsl:if test="@rowspan &gt; 1">}</xsl:if>}</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".=''"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@rowspan &gt; 1">\multirow{<xsl:value-of select="@rowspan" />}{\linewidth}{<xsl:apply-templates />}</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:if test="@colspan='1' and @align='center'">\multicolumn{1}{c}</xsl:if>{<xsl:apply-templates />}</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:if test="following-sibling::td"> &amp; </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I am facing is that the second (to fifth) 'tr' should appear as:

```
    &&{A} & 
    {a}
    \\
```

instead of:

```
    &&{A} & 
    &&{a}
    \\
```

Note that before last cell content "a" it adds extra two ampersands. Which should only appear before "A". The two ampersands represent the rowspan which make two empty cell to current row in LaTeX. How can this be fixed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021926/xml-table-to-latex Element `tbody` must be transformed/added to your solution by yourself. the outcome is nearly your expected output. Give it a try and adjust it.

Comment: @uL1: I have tried changing that code and it inserts two ampersand on second row. But that should repeat for third to fifth row as well.

Comment: @Jagath, have you got the solution, for the table converting issue?

Comment: @TeX_learner This is an old post. I might have fixed that somehow. Could not recall it now. Well, I will check and post here if I find a solution.